# How do I replace cells in Column A of Excel if the column I'm pulling from is partially blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an old list of names in Column A, and I want to replace them with the update names in Column B. What function can I use to replace only the cells that need updating? I basically want to keep the old Column A list but override the wrong names with new ones in Column B.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please provide some sample data and what the desired output for the sample would be?

Answer (score 2):

Start with column C and use `if(b2="",a2,b2)` and copy all the way down and then copy column C and paste values over column A.  Or leave column C dynamic as the completed list.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have data (names) in Column A,
some of which need to be updated (replaced) by values in the same row of Column B. 
Some data in Column A are correct, and the adjoining cells are blank:

[image: array of names in Excel]

Select the B data (cells B1 through B5 in my example, above). 
Click at the top of the A data (cell A1). 
Click on “Paste” → “Paste Special …”. 
In the “Paste Special” dialog box, click on “Skip Blanks” and “OK”.

[image: “Paste Special” dialog box]

(You may need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to complete the operation.)